# Kafka connect string to json in Postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have a topic with string containing json. For example a message could be:

```
'{"id":"foo", "datetime":1}'
```

In this topic everything is considered as string.

I would like to send messages in `postgresql` table with `kafka-connect`. My goal is to let `postgresql` to understand that messages are `json`. Indeed, `postgresql` [handles pretty well `json`](https://blog.codeship.com/unleash-the-power-of-storing-json-in-postgres/).

How to tell kafka-connect or postgresql that messages are in fact json ?

Thanks

EDIT:

For now, I use `./bin/connect-standalone config/connect-standalone.properties config/sink-sql-rules.properties`.

With:

- connect-standalone.properties

  ```
  bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
  key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
  value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
  key.converter.schemas.enable=false
  value.converter.schemas.enable=false
  internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
  internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
  internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
  internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
  offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
  offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
  rest.port=8084
  plugin.path=share/java
  ```
- sink-sql-rules.properties

  ```
  name=mysink
  connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
  tasks.max=1

  # The topics to consume from - required for sink connectors like this one
  topics=mytopic

  # Configuration specific to the JDBC sink connector.
  connection.url=***
  connection.user=***
  connection.password=***

  mode=timestamp+incremeting
  auto.create=true
  auto.evolve=true
  table.name.format=mytable
  batch.size=500
  ```

EDIT2:

With those conf I get this error:
`org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: No fields found using key and value schemas for table`

Comment: Please show your Kafka Connect configuration

Comment: Done in edit, thanks! For now, it doesn't work.

Comment: Please clarify what doesn't work... What errors do you get? You have no schema as part of your data, so `schemas.enable=true` will not work see https://rmoff.net/2017/09/06/kafka-connect-jsondeserializer-with-schemas-enable-requires-schema-and-payload-fields/

Comment: Yes I see it, I desable schemas. I also add the error in edit2. Hope it will help :) I am testing lot of things because I don't find what I want in doc. Thanks!

Comment: Again, you'll need to set `value.converter.schemas.enable=false`, for starters

Comment: Ok thanks, I remove it from `sink-sql-rules.properties` because it's in `connect-standalone.properties`. Still got same error.

Comment: Can you show the schema for the table you're trying to insert into?

Comment: For now, I do not have a schema because I use `auto.create=true`.

Comment: And did the table get created? Or does the error happen before that?